# (iphone) How to play the same sound from multiple views using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Tags: iphone, audio, audiotoolbox

I'd like to play button tap sound from various UIButton instances.

I'm planning to create a singleton to hold "SystemSoundID" of sound files that will be shared across many buttons.

Will this work? (SystemSoundID won't change during app's lifetime?)
Is there a other recommended way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Use audio file in app delegate class and you can you your audio file through out whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to sub-class `UIButton` and override its any of the touch event (as you want) and play sound.... by this way you don't have to worry about playing sound each time, which will be the case even you put the code in 'appdelegate'